# Merging data frames cross-sectionally

Tags: pandas, merge

I experimented a lot with `merge` and `join` and after re-reading the documentation and checking questions here I want to ask how do I merge the following two dataframes from this minimal working example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods = 5)
stock_id_msft = ['MSFT']*5
stock_id_aapl = ['AAPL']*5

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[dates, stock_id_msft])), 
                                  names = ['date', 'stock_id'])

df_msft = pd.DataFrame(index = index,
                       data  = np.random.rand(5)*10,
                       columns = ['price'])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[dates, stock_id_aapl])), 
                                  names = ['date', 'stock_id'])
df_aapl = pd.DataFrame(index = index, 
                       data = np.random.rand(5),
                       columns= ['price'])
```

so that the resulting dataframe is multi indexed and has one entry for each date with two rows for each `stock_id` i.e. the resulting dataframe would be indexed like

```
[('2020-01-01', 'AAPL'),
 ('2020-01-01', 'MSFT'),
 ('2020-01-02', 'AAPL'),
 ('2020-01-02', 'MSFT'),
 ('2020-01-03', 'AAPL'),
 ('2020-01-03', 'MSFT'),
 ('2020-01-04', 'AAPL'),
 ('2020-01-04', 'MSFT'),
 ('2020-01-05', 'AAPL'),
 ('2020-01-05', 'MSFT')]
```

and I would have a cross-section of stocks by date. I know I can `concat` and `groupby` but I want the final dataframe to have a price for each stock in the cross-section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas concat method:

```
>>> pd.concat([df_aapl,df_msft]).sort_index()
            price
date    stock_id    
2020-01-01  AAPL    0.663115
MSFT    4.178832
2020-01-02  AAPL    0.267694
MSFT    0.538919
2020-01-03  AAPL    0.822265
MSFT    7.972534
2020-01-04  AAPL    0.164536
MSFT    2.813109
2020-01-05  AAPL    0.285003
MSFT    4.158308
>>> pd.concat([df_aapl,df_msft]).sort_index().index
MultiIndex([('2020-01-01', 'AAPL'),
        ('2020-01-01', 'MSFT'),
        ('2020-01-02', 'AAPL'),
        ('2020-01-02', 'MSFT'),
        ('2020-01-03', 'AAPL'),
        ('2020-01-03', 'MSFT'),
        ('2020-01-04', 'AAPL'),
        ('2020-01-04', 'MSFT'),
        ('2020-01-05', 'AAPL'),
        ('2020-01-05', 'MSFT')],
       names=['date', 'stock_id'])
```

Comment: if it's just the index you need, it should be less expensive if you just do the union of the indexes, instead of combining the dataframes, only to pull out the index

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @sammywemmy, I do need the actual data columns to run some cross-sectional linear and non-linear regressions as well as some other analysis. But I'll keep that in mind if a use case for only the index comes up.